# Python py not executing in other PC

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a technical questions on python script.
I have developed code on my laptop and I want to move it in another one.
I installed python there, put when I try to double click on the .py file it is not working. Like the cmd screen goes away in a second.
Do you know why?

(if I open python through cmd it is working, so it is in path and it works)

Comment: Check what executable is associated with py files

Comment: What happens when you type `python <script name>` in cmd on the 2nd computer?

Comment: Maybe the script runs very quickly and finishes.

Comment: It is executing, and after it's done, it returns to the screen, that will terminate after that. You can add something to the end of that script that will force the window to remain open, like a `raw_input`, that will wait for an enter to finish the script.

Comment: No it is not executing because it does not do what it should be doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably happening is that there is an error being thrown on your new computer which causes command prompt to just instantly close.

The best way to run a python script is from an open command prompt/terminal. To do this open a command prompt and move into the directory of your python file. For example, if the file you are trying to run is located at C:\Users\Davide\PythonScripts, then open a command prompt and type

```
cd C:\Users\Davide\PythonScripts
```

Now your command window is in the folder that you want to run files out of.

Next you want to tell Python to run your script. This can be done by typing "python ". For example, if your script is name my_script.py, you would type

```
python my_script.py
```

What this is doing is telling your computer "open an instance of Python where you are running my_script.py." If there are any errors thrown, the command window will stay open after python closes and you can see what is going on.

Most likely, there is a package you are trying to import which it cannot find because it was not installed on your other computer. If at the top of your file you have "import xxx" or "from xxx import yyy" lines, your other computer might not be finding those modules and just throwing an error that instantly closes command prompt when you just double click the .py file.

Comment: I have almost the same issue but my problem is that my script was working before and now it is not working I have created the script which is using geocoding API.
Also, I tired  a program which just uses print statement and it is also not working